# ModuleNotFoundError : When importing from directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import, importerror

My files are:

```
main.py
dir/func.py
dir/mod.py
```

My *main.py* has `from dir import func` 
My *func.py* has `import mod`

When I run *main.py* it gives me:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod'`

I am using Python 3.10, so what I have read, I do not need the *__init__.py* file.

Now, it does work if I put `from dir import mod` in *func.py*. Is there any way to not have to do that. Is there a better, more elegant way? Because I might have to be calling *func.py* from different directories in the future.

Comment: try from . import mod or from .mod import mod (not sure exactly)

Comment: @SimonHawe `from . import mod` works. Thank you. But ideally I am looking for something more elegant. Because in my real project, the dir folder has many different modules. With them all importing each other, this would mean I would have import all in all of them. Is no other solution exists, I would have to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new package directory

```
from foldername.filename import func
```

make sure to include an empty _*init*_.py file in the directory. This file tells Python to treat the directory as a package

Comment: I added \_\_init_\_.py in the dir folder. It is giving me the same error. And what would `from foldername.filename import func` correspond in my case? Is it just `from dir import mod`

Comment: foldername is the dir name in your case and the filename is the func,py without .py